# Regarding linking string in combobox to output data

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, combobox

I have a combo box in Visual Studio and I edited strings in the combo box to display 5 items, I have tried to look online to see how, once a person clicks one of the items, to display information about that item. (Yet if no item is clicked, to leave the form blank)

For example, a fridge by Whirlpool, can cool to 1 degree Celsius, it costs $400 and is delivered within 24 hours.

So once a person clicks "Whirlpool Fridge" in the Combo box it should pop out with this on the form labels/textbox

Manufacturer: Whirlpool
Max cooling: 1 Celsius 
Cost: $400
Delivery: Within 24 hours

Also, I tried to find if it were possible to display a picture of the fridge in a picturebox. Yet, I haven't come across a solution to this.

I really appreciate the help and I am sorry to have bored you with this question!

Note: If you're going to link me to a site, I would appreciate it if you could at least explain how to do it, or for others who like the spoon-feeding-spoon, just paste it up and I'll figure it out. Thank you again! <:D

EDIT:

I am using Windows Forms Application

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, WebForms, or MVC+Razor?

Comment: Windows Forms Application is what I am using.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can make this more simple is through data binding.

Let's say you have an appliance object:

```
public class Appliance
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string ApplianceType { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public string ShowString
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", Make, ApplianceType); }
    }
}
```

And you want to bind a list of these to a combobox. You can define what properties are shown in the combobox and cast the selected object back to the class:

```
List<Appliance> appliances = new List<Appliance>();

// populate list; for example:
appliances.Add(new Appliance
{
    Make = "Whirlpool",
    ApplianceType = "Fridge",
    Model = "WP-300",
    Price = 500.00,
    Info = "Cools to 4C!"
});
appliances.Add(new Appliance
{
    Make = "Maytag",
    ApplianceType = "Dishwasher",
    Model = "MT-80A",
    Price = 400.00,
    Info = "Washes spot free!"
});

cmbApplianceList.DataSource = appliances;
cmbApplianceList.DisplayMember = "ShowString";
```

(There's also `ValueMember` which you can bind to a unique property.)

When someone selects an item in the combobox, you can do the following to act on the selected class:

```
cmbApplianceList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Appliance selectedAppliance = (Appliance)cmbApplianceList.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedAppliance.Info);
}
```

In this case, a message box shows the `Info` property of the selected Appliance.

Comment: Alright, it's making sense! Where do I put the list though? Inside the combobox code method or?

Comment: I found where to put it, you've saved my day JYelton! :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Windows Form that takes the required values as parameter.

```
public partial class MyItemForm : Form
{
    public myItemForm(string item, double costs, int time, string picturepath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = item+ ": 1 Celsius Cost: $"+costs.ToString()+" Delivery: Within "+time.toString() +" hours."
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picturepath;
    }
}
```

The form simply takes the parameters, sets them as the LabelText.
Same happens with the picturepath.

In the main, you have to do something like this in:

```
    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MyItemForm itemform = new MyItemForm(ComboBox1.Text, getCosts(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex), getTime(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex), getPicturePath(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex));
       itemform.Show();
    }
```

So everytime a user changes the Item in the ComboBox, the event gets called.
You have to figure out the get-methods yourself.

I hope it's clear though.

Remember: This is an example! You have to figure out the right code yourself.

Comment: I have the forms all set, the combobox is in a form and will display only within that form, it should not have to cross over onto any forms as I am keeping them separate. I am just wanting to find out how to, for example, when a user clicks the first item in the list (position 0), that I can do a method to display the information in corresponding labels/text boxes.

Comment: You mean something like:
MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedText);